# finding an available machine for RDP out of many

Tags: c#, java, remote-desktop

I have a few machines running Windows 7 that has access from within the LAN using MSTSC (Remote desktop)

I want to make a web app that will show which of the machines is available at the moment for remote connection (no one else is connected to the same computer at the moment) - or else what is the name of the connected PC

As for the web app I have no problem - I have a PHP server that supposed to be notified when a machine status is changed

What is the best possible way of creating the process that will run on the machines, detect a status change (connection/disconnection) - and then notify the server about the change?

I prefer java based solutions. C# is a second priority but is also a possibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at WTSEnumerateSessions function from Remote Desktop Services API?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383833(v=vs.85).aspx
You do not really need to run any code on the machine that you are querying. You can poll your computers from the server periodically. You can access Remote Desktop Service API from managed code (C#). Not sure about Java.

Comment: I saw it, but it is c++, isn't it?

Comment: You can call any Win32 API from C# using P/Invoke. Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx. It may look complicated but it is not at all.

Comment: The [Cassia library](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/) is another option if you'd rather not deal with the P/Invokes yourself.